Oracle table data representation in PowerBI
I have a table in Oracle with data as below: 

Need to represent the data in PowerBI in below format:

I tried transposing the data, but it didn't work as expected.

Go to Power Query. Rename the column on the original table the way you want to see the row headers. Select the Month column, right-click on it, and select 'Unpivot Other Columns':

You will get this result:

After loading, create a Matrix, and use Month as Columns, Attribute as Rows, and Value as Values.
Final result:


Thanks for your inputs. I am able to get the data in specified format. But the total is adding all the counts. TOTAL_ON_PREM_SERVERS is the total of On-Prem count  and TOTAL SERVER is the overall count. I have to segregate the data as per the screenshot above.

For the calculations of +/- Prev Month, I tried visual calculations in PowerBI , but not able to work on the below pointers.
Below items I have to remove from the Matrix.


I only need the difference for the last month always , and it should be dynamic (i.e - in this case mar'24 - feb'24 , next month it will be apr'24-mar'24 & so on)


only the last month difference should be visible, so if i hide overall field is getting hidden.


Format the difference field to numeric (without .00), Not able format the field.


Appreciate any help !

In Power Query, I right-clicked the newly created 'Attribute' column. Then selected 'Add column from examples'.

I typed for On-Prems - On Prem, for Cloud VMs - Cloud, and for Totals - null.
This populated all rows as this example.

I renamed the column 'Type'.
From the previously created matrix, I filtered out the Totals:

I added the newly created Type column in the rows:

The result gives subtotals for each Type + Total VMs at the end:

You can position the Row totals at the bottom like this:

I hope this helped.

Thanks for your help. I am able to get the Total count separately. For calculating the difference +/- Prev Month, i have created a measure to find the difference between values for (current month -1) & (current month -2), but it's not working any suggestion will be helpful.
